# How to find more than one elements with ids in a single iteration

Tags: jquery

Below is my HTML

```
 <div id='d1'></div>
 <div id='d2'>Yes</div>
 <div id='d4'></div>
 <div id='d3'>No</div>
```

My Requirement is to find DIV tags with ids d2,d3 in a single iteration and add radio buttons to it.

Please someone help me.

Comment: Do they have a common parent?  This may be far simpler than maintaining a list.  Are you able to give them a class?  Also a more maintainable route for editing this content in the future and not messing with the script at all.

Comment: @Omeid - He's not using any IDs more than once in the question above.

Comment: My Bad at a glance I thought they are same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#d2, #d3").html('<input type="radio" />');
```

is it what are you looking for?

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/d41b5